# Count Booleans by Column in Array of Arrays

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have an array of arrays with booleans:

```
[[False False  True ..., False  True False]
 [False  True  True ...,  True False  True]
 [False False False ...,  True  True False]
 ..., 
 [False False False ..., False False False]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]]
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

The following code counts Trues in the **rows**

```
results = []
for r in my_array:
   results.append(np.sum(r))
```

How can I count the number of booleans by column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[numpy.sum](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) supports summing up an array across multiple axes. Use the `0`th axis for columns, and the `1`st axis for rows.

```
>>> arr = np.ndarray(shape=(3, 4), dtype=bool)
>>> arr
array([[False,  True, False,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
>>> np.sum(arr, axis=0)
array([0, 1, 0, 2])
>>> np.sum(arr, axis=1)
array([2, 1, 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you need a pure Python solution I would go with [itertools.izip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip).

```
# Example
# itertools.izip('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax By
results = []

for r in itertools.izip(*my_array):
    results.append(sum(r))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I have a numpy array

```
a = numpy.ones([3, 4])
>>> a
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

numpy has a really neat feature that let's you specify slices in multiple dimensions, such that array[row_indices, col_indices] is meaningful.  Consider the following:

```
>>> sum(a[:,0])
3.0
```

I just added all row values that have a column index of 0.  Replace that value with an iterable and you have your solution.